# How to set value input time from clickable table javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, web, setvalue

I want to set time value from javascript when tr table clicked, but it's just work on first row. then if i try to alert (not set value) its working idk whats the problem, here is my code :

Note : table code is to long so i cannot share but table id is example_table

I hope time value can be set every click any table row

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#example_table").delegate("tr", "click", function() {
    var d = new Date(),
      h = (d.getHours() < 10 ? '0' : '') + d.getHours(),
      m = (d.getMinutes() < 10 ? '0' : '') + d.getMinutes();
    now = h + ':' + m;

    $("#start").val(now);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="time" name="start" class="form-control form-control-border" id="start">
```

Comment: You cannot use same id for multiple elements either change it to class or use unique ids for `start` assuming that you have same id for multiple inputs on different trs .

Comment: Hi, Any particular reason you removed the "accept " from my answer?

Answer (score 0):

It would have been great to have a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with at least 3 rows.

1. jQuery `.delegate` is deprecated for `.on`
2. Use relative selection
3. IDs need to be unique.
4. use toISOString to get the time in hh:mm in the simplest way.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#example_table").on("click", "tr", function() {
      $(this).find(".start").val(new Date().toISOString().slice(11, 16));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody id="example_table">
    <tr>
      <td>Click on the row</td>
      <td><input type="time" name="start" class="form-control form-control-border start"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Click on the row</td>
      <td><input type="time" name="start" class="form-control form-control-border start"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Click on the row</td>
      <td><input type="time" name="start" class="form-control form-control-border start"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

If you have a button in one cell and the time in another, you can use `closest` to navigate to the row and then to the input:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#example_table").on("click", ".now", function() {
      $(this).closest("tr").find(".start").val(new Date().toISOString().slice(11, 16));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody id="example_table">
    <tr>
      <td><button type="button" class="now">Now</button></td>
      <td><input type="time" name="start" class="form-control form-control-border start"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><button type="button" class="now">Now</button></td>
      <td><input type="time" name="start" class="form-control form-control-border start"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><button type="button" class="now">Now</button></td>
      <td><input type="time" name="start" class="form-control form-control-border start"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```